# Cloned Elements Not Showing In Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, clone

i have a div on my page with some child elements, now on the click of a button i would like that div to be cloned along with it's child elements, this works however certain elements are not shown in the original after the cloning, i've been at it for a while trying to figure out why this was happening.  I checked my css and removed where i had "poisition: absolute" for those elements that were not showing after the clone and everything worked. Is there a way to bypass this? I would really like to know.

**This is my Javascript:**

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#lnkAddNewAnswer').click(function() {
         $('.answer-txt-area').first().clone(true, true).appendTo('.answers-container');
       });

       $('.answer-txt-area').hover(
         function() {
           $(this).find('.options').show();
         },
         function() {
           $(this).find('.options').hide();
         }
       );


     });
```

```css
.answers-container {
  position: relative;
}
.answer-txt-area {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC !important;
  border-left: 5px solid #DCDCDC !important;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.answer-txt-area .options {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(149, 183, 93, 0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.answer-txt-area .options ul {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.answer-txt-area .options ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers-container">
  <div class="answer-txt-area">
    <div class="options">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="lnkButton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> <span class="text">Set as correct answer</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="lnkButton"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove"></i> <span class="text">Remove answer</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type answer here.." required="required" name="answer[]" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div class="selected-answer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in the browser before the clone:
[image]

This is what it looks like after the clone:
[image]

Comment: Please add the fukl result HTML code not the template code (whichever template engine you use). I mean the `{{ Form ... ` thing

Comment: Can you use the actual HTML output for your code snippet instead?

Comment: Yes please sorry about that, i must have missed that part, i have edited my question.

Comment: uʍopǝpısdn's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is being cloned, it's just not being positioned where you think it is.

Give `.answer-txt-area` a position and it will work as expected:

```
.answer-txt-area {
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2x9vumtk/)

`.answer-txt-area .options` is being positioned relative to closest positioned ancestor. Because the closest positioned ancestor is `.answers-container`, your `.options` within the initial element and each of it's clones are positioned on top of each other